# Native Development tab doesn't show up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I have no idea what's going on. I have been following some tutorials, and have properly set up my project with the NDK. I did mess around with things a bit last week, but my project still seems to work correctly. I am trying to find the NDK path but the tab is no longer there...
[image]

The Native Development tab should be where the red bar is. I know it was there sometime last week. Is it possible I deleted something from eclipse that would remove this tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The address to where I unzipped my NDK folder wasn't added to my computer's PATH variable. Strange, as I distinctly remember doing that at one point, but until that address is added to the PATH variable the option just doesn't show up in Eclipse.

If anyone knows of anyway that the PATH variable is changed other than through the users doing, please let me know. I don't remember editing the PATH variable and have no idea why I would have.

For Windows 7 Professional :

**Start**->**Right Click On Computer**->**Properties**->**Advanced System Settings**->**Environment Variables**

I had already had a `Path` variable under `System variables`, and a `PATH` variable under `User variables...`

In both variables, I added the address to my NDK folder. Separate the new address from the one already existing inside with a semi-colon.

The tutorial that helped me figure this out is [here at step #5](http://permadi.com/blog/2011/09/setting-up-android-jni-projects-in-windows-eclipse-and-sequoyah/)

Comment: "The address to where I unzipped my NDK folder wasn't added to my computer's PATH variable." I believe that is expected behavior.

Comment: You also need to set ANDROID_NDK_ROOT and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT. See [Recommended NDK Directory?](https://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/a998e139aca71d77)

Comment: "In both variables, I added the address to my NDK folder." I believe you only need to set it for system - the user will inherit it.

Comment: You're right, it is expected behavior. However at the time, I had thought I had already done this. I was not expecting the action of unzipping the file to add the directory to my path.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a problem with loading the NDK plugin. One thing you can do is open the Error Log view (menu Window > Show View > Error Log.)

This lists all errors internal to Eclipse. I recommend erasing the whole log and restarting Eclipse. Then you will see the errors related to loading plugins. I bet the problem is listed there.

Comment: Thanks, I found a whole lot of errors. One of which that looks to be of interest is `Sequoyah Android Native Code Support will be ignored because it is already installed.` What the heck does that mean? `Problems occured when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".` Any idea what these could mean, or if they are even the ones that I want?

Comment: Thanks anyway, I can't get the bounty so I'll just give it to you. Enjoy :D

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be any more helpful.