# Android - 'Couldn't load Foo: findLibrary returned null'

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I know that there are already posts about this error around stack overflow, but from what I have found here on SO and on Google don't line up with my problem.

I am trying to run my application, but whenever a native function is called my program crashes, and I get the following `LogCat`...

```
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.initMain(MainMenu.java:241)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at my.eti.commander.MainMenu.onCreate(MainMenu.java:81)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load RelayAPI: findLibrary returned null
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:429)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    at my.eti.commander.RelayAPIModel$NativeCalls.<clinit>(RelayAPIModel.java:432)
08-01 09:15:57.448: E/AndroidRuntime(16966):    ... 15 more
```

Here is my `Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
EXTRA_CFLAGS := -DANDROID
LOCAL_MODULE := RelayAPI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := RelayAPI.c
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

Here is a picture of my jni folder...Only RelayAPI will be used, stringstuff is an extra file that isn't used.

[image]

I store all of my native functions in a separate class so that they can be called statically. This isn't the problem though, because I've been moving them around quite a bit but I just decided this would be the best way for me to get it done.

```
public static class NativeCalls {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary( "RelayAPI");
    }

    public native static byte InitRelayJava();

    public native static void FreeRelayJava();
}
```

Comment: i think the error is coming becoz of libs,,,,Add correctly jar files

Comment: Build it as a shared library. I think it may be because you're building it as an executable. I don't think System.loadLibrary can load executables

Comment: Where have you copied your jar/ or other Library files in your project??

Comment: I really have no idea what files you're talking about, sorry. What purpose do the files serve? I have only been altering my .c/.h/.mk files in the jni folder and the Java files in my /src directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I've gotten passed the error. I had asked a different question last month, and while trying to solve that, this error went away. It had to do with setting my `environment PATH variable` to the NDK folder location. [This is a link to a more in depth answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11761058/1435712)

Answer (score 1):

shouldn't include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) be used instead of include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to build your library before running your application (that use the library) with `ndk-build`

Answer (score 0):

`BUILD_EXECUTABLE` is wrong, this will build an executable (hint, hint..) instead of a shared library. When you use `System.loadLibrary(..)` you have to use **`BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY`**. If it still does not work, there might be another mistake but using `BUILD_EXECUTABLE` for something intended to be used as a shared library is wrong even though it 'may' work under some circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this issue too, but for my situation,
You have to add processor based library to your project libs folder.
If you are using eclipse.

[image]