# Trying to use external .jar not working in Android

Tags: java, android, jar, logcat

I'm trying to get a small aac radio stream to play in an android application. I'm trying to use http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/ but I have never had too much luck with code.google.com because I find a lot of the projects hard to use.

I downloaded the zip and I think I set it up correctly in my project properties.

When I try to run the line of code to play the file I get this error:

```
11-15 16:28:25.750: E/AndroidRuntime(3626): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load aacdecoder: findLibrary returned null
```

The code I use is this:

```
import com.spoledge.aacdecoder.AACPlayer;
...
AACPlayer aacPlayer = new AACPlayer();
aacPlayer.playAsync( "http://..." );
```

Any ideas? I don't think it's with aacdecoder project itself, I think that I'm actually setting it up incorrectly. I don't get any red lines in eclipse. Ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you forget to copy `*.so` (native libraries), because I've just created new project, added `*.jar` to **Java Build Path** (you've already done that) and it played stream fine. My code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new Button(this));

    AACPlayer aacPlayer = new AACPlayer();
    aacPlayer.playAsync( "http://http.yourmuze.com:8000/play/paradise/h.aac" );
}
```

And don't forget to add permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: I forgot the permission (thanks) but what do you mean `*.so`. I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: Native (c++) library (`so` is just an library extension). Read this - http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html. The library consist of two parts: 1) native (`.so`) is c++ port to android 2) java (`.jar` library) is just a wrapper of native library. So your application can't find first library - add it! It is in folder `libs/armaebi`.

Comment: Do I add the `.so` to the /libs?

Comment: Just copy all contents from zipped folder `aacdecoder-android-libs-0.6.1` to your project's `libs` folder.

Comment: Hrm... seems to work, but really "laggy". Another question is what the difference between "armeabi" and "armeabi-v7a"

Comment: Google it, my friend https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=difference+between+armeabi+and+armeabi-v7a&aq=0&oq=armeabi%22+and+%22armeabi-v7a&aqs=chrome.1.57j0j62l3.1832&sugexp=chrome,mod=13&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at these links, they have similar problems

- [Android - 'Couldn't load Foo: findLibrary returned null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760284/android-couldnt-load-foo-findlibrary-returned-null)
- [Android NDK java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: findLibrary returned null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037966/android-ndk-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-findlibrary-returned-null)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure it's in the /lib folder and in the project properties in the build path.  And make sure in the order its listed a higher than /src.

Comment: Updated my question to show my properties. Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Does it look correct? I have the jar in my /libs. If I delete the jar in the libs, then I get red lines. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Android uses the `/libs` folder (with an "s").